# ntpdate reports failure after successfully getting the offset

Tags: ntpd

`ntpdate -d` sometimes prints `no server suitable` error even though it successfully connected to the server and printed the offset. Why?

In my scripts in need to distinguish network errors and this one. How to force it exit with zero status?

good:

```
# ntpdate -d 10.3.2.67
12 Nov 13:23:21 ntpdate[6565]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Mon Jul 15 09:22:50 UTC 2013 (1)
Looking for host 10.3.2.67 and service ntp
host found : ec-prod-app-1
transmit(10.3.2.67)
receive(10.3.2.67)
transmit(10.3.2.67)
receive(10.3.2.67)
transmit(10.3.2.67)
receive(10.3.2.67)
transmit(10.3.2.67)
receive(10.3.2.67)
server 10.3.2.67, port 123
stratum 4, precision -21, leap 00, trust 000
refid [10.3.2.67], delay 0.02574, dispersion 0.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    d9eee40d.738ce7c1  Thu, Nov 12 2015 13:10:21.451
originate timestamp: d9eee719.a97c80cf  Thu, Nov 12 2015 13:23:21.662
transmit timestamp:  d9eee719.a9245fa8  Thu, Nov 12 2015 13:23:21.660
filter delay:  0.02579  0.02586  0.02574  0.02574
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 0.001251 0.001187 0.001244 0.001243
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.02574, dispersion 0.00000
offset 0.001244

12 Nov 13:23:21 ntpdate[6565]: adjust time server 10.3.2.67 offset 0.001244 sec
```

bad:

```
# ntpdate -d 10.3.2.68
12 Nov 13:23:24 ntpdate[6566]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Mon Jul 15 09:22:50 UTC 2013 (1)
Looking for host 10.3.2.68 and service ntp
host found : ec-prod-app-2
transmit(10.3.2.68)
receive(10.3.2.68)
transmit(10.3.2.68)
receive(10.3.2.68)
transmit(10.3.2.68)
receive(10.3.2.68)
transmit(10.3.2.68)
receive(10.3.2.68)
10.3.2.68: Server dropped: strata too high
server 10.3.2.68, port 123
stratum 16, precision -20, leap 11, trust 000
refid [10.3.2.68], delay 0.02574, dispersion 0.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Mon, Jan  1 1900  3:00:00.000
originate timestamp: d9eee71b.a14c710c  Thu, Nov 12 2015 13:23:23.630
transmit timestamp:  d9eee71c.5e083201  Thu, Nov 12 2015 13:23:24.367
filter delay:  0.02577  0.02574  0.02574  0.02577
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: -0.73732 -0.73732 -0.73733 -0.73734
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.02574, dispersion 0.00000
offset -0.737324

12 Nov 13:23:24 ntpdate[6566]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you notice the:

```
10.3.2.68: Server dropped: strata too high
```

And the:

```
stratum 16, precision -20, leap 11, trust 000
```

Lines in your output?

The `ntp` client thinks that the time source is not sane enough (i.e. not syncing with a lower stratum server) enough

Comment: I'm writing a script to detect hung ntpd in farm. Can I ignore this very error and not ignore others?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. I don't think you should ignore an error like this and start investigating NTP server 10.3.2.68. Of course you can forcely exit a script with exit code 0 using `exit 0` but, again, I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for. Please update your question and be more specific in what you want to do.